# Image in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

$\def\im{\operatorname{im}}\def\coker{\operatorname{coker}}$For a morphism $ f: A\to B$ in an abelian category, we let $\im f:=\ker(\coker f)$.

Then the morphism $A\to \im f$ is an epimorphism and $\coker(\ker f\to A).$

May I have their proofs?

Comment: See steps 4 and 5 in t.b.'s answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45008).

Comment: I have understood all steps. Thank you again.