# Equivalent definition of Abelian Category, exercise.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

So I came across this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45008/equivalent-conditions-for-a-preabelian-category-to-be-abelian?rq=1) earlier today. I tried to understand it but I am stuck at a seemingly easy point. Apologies in advance as I am really new at this type of stuff!

My question is that the OP said the converse is easy but I am really struggling to see how to prove it. For the sake of convenience, I have copied the question as follows:

[image]

The proposition I wanted to prove is that if $\bar{f}$ is an iso and $f$ is a mono then $f$ is the kernel of the coker$(f)$ map.

I know that what I need to prove is that if $X\to B\to \text{Coker} f$ is $0$ then there exists a unique map $X\to A$ such that it makes everything commute but I wasn't sure how to use either conditions given above.

I have thought about $A\to \text{im}(f)\to B$, which is an epi at first, mono next, but I couldn't go any further, either.

Could someone plese help me with a quite detailed answer? I would be very grateful if anyone could! Admittedly, I am quite bad at the concept of mono/epi etc. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the image of a monomorph is isomorphic to the map itself, so $f:A\to B$ is isomorphic to $\text{im} f:\text{Im} f\to B$. Thus, it's a kernel

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you for letting me know! I didnt know this fact before. Just to double check, what do you mean by two morphisms are isomorphic? Do you simple mean that $A$ is isomorphic to Im$f$?

Comment: It's more than that. It's isomorphic, and the morphisms commute in the triangle with the two morphisms and the isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us note that because $f$ is mono, we have $\ker f = 0$. Therefore, we have that $\DeclareMathOperator{coim}{coim}$$\coim f$ is an isomorphism, since it is the coequalizer of two equal maps $0 \to A$.

If moreover we have $\overline{f}$ is an isomorphism, then we see that $\overline{f} \circ \coim f$ is an isomorphism. This means that $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}$since $\im_f$ is a kernel and isomorphic to $f$, $f$ is also a kernel. In particular, $f$ is the kernel of its cokernel.

For the epi argument, it's exactly the same but in the opposite category.