# Additive Structure in Abelian Categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm beginning to study abelian categories. The definition I'm using is this:

> A category is said to be abelian if:
>
> $1)$ it has a zero object
>
> $2)$ it has all binary products and binary coproducts
>
> $3)$ it has all kernels and cokernels
>
> $4)$ all monomorphisms and epimorphisms are normal.

I'm trying to prove that if a category $C$ is abelian, than for every $A,B\in\text{Ob}(C)$, the set $\hom_C(A,B)$ has an abelian group structure with neutral element $0:A\to B$ (the zero morphism), and that the composition of morphism is bilinear with respect to this group operation.

In simple examples like the category of $R$-modules or $K$-vector spaces, there is an obvious additive group structure, but in the general context, I have no idea how to define this group operation.

What is the idea?

Comment: I'm not sure this is right; I think you need to also specify that products and coproducts agree (in a particular way). See http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/ for a discussion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, that was a great article, thanks!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm looking at the following theorem from the article you linked: "A semiadditive category $C$ is canonically enriched over $\text{CMon}$. The identity in each commutative monoid $\text{Hom}(a, b)$ is the zero morphism $0_{a, b}$". In the beginning of the proof, you say that $f\oplus 0: a\oplus a\to b\oplus b$ factors through  $a\oplus 0\to b\oplus 0$, and using $a\oplus 0\simeq a$, $b\oplus 0\simeq b$, you conclude that $f+0=f$. How do you formalize this conclusion?

Comment: You don't need to specify that products and coproducts agree ; it is always the case by the short five lemma, but there's a lot of work needed to do that. It is done in Chapter 2 of Peter Freyd's "Abelian Categories", which is available online at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've read that abelian categories can naturally be enriched in $\mathbf{Ab}.$ How does this actually work?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625477/ive-read-that-abelian-categories-can-naturally-be-enriched-in-mathbfab-ho)