# finite products in R-mod (R is a ring)

Tags: category-theory, modules, products, universal-property

I understand that the finite products in R-mod are the direct product of  modules. But I am not sure how universal property is satisfied by the direct products? Can someone please explain.

Also, I see that finite products are same as coproducts in R-mod. Why is it so?

Comment: For the latter question, the obvious morphism is an isomorphism. In any pre-additive category, it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just demonstrate this for the binary case, as all other finite cases work essentially the same way.
Suppose $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules, then the direct product is just given by the Cartesian product $M\times N$ of their underlying sets equipped with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.
In particular, the *uniqueness* part of the universal property of the product is going to be guaranteed by the fact that module homomorphisms are structure-preserving functions of the underlying sets.

Therefore, we would only need to check the *existence* part.
Suppose $Z$ is some $R$-module with homomorphisms $f:Z\to M$ and $g:Z\to N$. As I mentioned above, these are special functions of the underlying sets, so they induce a unique *function* $(f,g):Z\to M\times N$ given by mapping $z\mapsto (f(z),g(z))$.
It just amounts now to checking that $(f,g)$ is a module homomorphism, which essentially just follows from how the module structure on $M\times N$ is defined.
Therefore, the direct product of $R$-modules forms the categorical product in $R\mathbf{Mod}$.

---

As for why $M\times N$ also serves as the *coproduct* (in the finite case), the first thing to do is come up with inclusion maps $\iota_M:M\to M\times N$ and $\iota_N:N\to M\times N$.
The natural choice is to define $\iota_M(m) := (m,0)$ and similarly $\iota_N(n) := (0,n)$.
By the way $M\times N$ is an $R$-module, these will be $R$-module homomorphisms.

From here, there are two ways to go.
If you know that the coproduct in $R\mathbf{Mod}$ is given by the direct sum, then it would be enough to observe that these inclusions realise $M$ and $N$ as submodules of $M\times N$ that are disjoint but span the entire module, hence giving that $M\times N\cong M\oplus N$.

Alternatively, you can just check that $M\times N$ with these inclusions will satisfy the universal property of the coproduct.
If $Z$ is an $R$-module with functions $f:M\to Z$ and $g:N\to Z$, then the desired induced map $h:M\times N\to Z$ is given by $h(m,n) := f(m) + g(n)$.
You can check that this is unique (by noting that $(m,n) = (m,0) + (0,n)$) and a module homomorphism. However, you might also notice that this is essentially the same reasoning as showing $M\times N\cong M\oplus N$.

It may be worthwhile to note that this breaks down in the infinite setting because an element of an arbitrary direct product may not necessarily admit a decomposition into a (necessarily finite!) sum of components, so in general the obvious map from the direct sum into the direct product will not be surjective.

As @rschwieb's comment mentions, the coincidence of the finite product and coproduct is a general phenomenon that occurs in any (pre)additive category. An argument for this is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25213/in-an-additive-category-why-is-finite-products-the-same-as-finite-coproducts) (note that the only difference between being pre-additive and additive is the latter is assumed to actually have finite co/products).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation @Shibai .  That was helpful!