# Products in the category R-Mod

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I have already shown that **Ab** is an Abelian category, in particular it has finite products. Using this, I want to show that **R-Mod** has finite products. I feel that what I have done makes sense, but I am very new to category theory, so I would appreciate if any mistakes are pointed out. I found this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3849098/815597 helpful but I am still a bit confused in writing out the details.

Since $R$-modules are abelian groups and $R$-linear maps are (abelian) group homomorphisms, given two $R$-modules $A,B$, there is a product $A\times B$ in **Ab**. This is the cartesian product with component-wise addition. Next, we define an $R$-module structure on $A\times B$ by considering scalar multiplication.

By the universal property of products in **Ab**, for every $R$-module $Z$ and pair of $R$-linear maps $f_A:Z\to A$, $f_B:Z\to B$, there is a unique map $\varphi:Z\to A\times B$ s.t. $\pi_A\circ\varphi=f_A$ and $\pi_B\circ \varphi=f_B$. Hence $\varphi=f_A\times f_B:z\mapsto (f_A(z),f_B(z))$ is a group homomorphism.

Lastly, we show that this $\varphi$ is a $R$-module map, which follows from the fact that $f_A$ and $f_B$ are. Does this argument show that for $A\times B$ is product in **R-Mod**?

Edit: Following Qiaochu's suggestion, I am adding the part on why $\varphi$ is $R$-module map. Let $r\in R$, $z\in Z$ any, $\varphi(rz)=(f_A(rz),f_B(rz))=(rf_A(z),rf_B(z))=r(f_A(z),f_B(z))=r\varphi(z)$. The second equality comes from the fact that $f_A$, $f_B$ are $R$-module maps, third equality comes from the module structure on $A\times B$ which is scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. You may be worried that you haven't done very much work here but what you're seeing is a special case of a much more general phenomenon: any category of algebraic structures has products (even infinite ones), and those products are just the cartesian product of sets together with the pointwise algebraic structure. This applies to groups, rings, modules, etc.

Comment: Indeed, that was what bothered me. Thank you :))

Comment: @frelg: you're welcome. If you want to work things out in more detail essentially all of the "actual work" of the argument is contained in the last bit "...which follows from the fact that $f_A$ and $f_B$ are."

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "category of algebraic structures".  Any variety of algebras, for example, has products (in fact that's a part of the HSP theorem).  On the other hand, the category of fields doesn't have products, and it would be reasonable to consider that a category of algebraic structures in a looser sense.

Comment: Sure. I had in mind a variety of algebras.